# Laravel using or inside routes to use multiple url as same as action

Tags: laravel

in `Laravel` i have this route group:

```php
Route::prefix('panel')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', AdminComponent::class);
    Route::get('/administrator', AdminComponent::class);
});
```

and my question is how can i combine this `urls` which they have the same behavior to open manage url

can i combine this routes to single route? for example:

```php
Route::prefix('panel')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/|administrator', AdminComponent::class);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
Route::prefix('panel')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/{url?}', function () {

        //redirect or return view here

    })->where(['url' => 'administrator']);

});
```

Adding another route like 'administrator2' would be:

```
->where(['url' => 'administrator|administrator2'])
```